# How to connect android device to TOR programmatically

Tags: proxy, torsocks, socks, android, java

I would like to build an application that connects the phone like Orxy/Orbot, although I cannot figure out how.

How might I connect to tor using java, or connect to the socks proxy tor interface in java.

Thank you stackers,

Good night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run Tor on your device - use a fully static build, after that - using TransPort and iptables(Android is Linux by kernel) you're doing the rest. That's it - no rocket science here. Keep in mind, to connect the whole device - you will need a root privileges for your app

Comment: Have you got sample code?

Comment: Check the Orbot's source code https://github.com/guardianproject/orbot